# I'm having issues optimizing a complex view in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization, view

I'm attempting to create a view to join in hierarchical data to a normalized dataset in SQL using a profileID field.

The issue that I'm having is that my company's hierarchy data is, for lack of a better term, gapped. There are startdate and enddate fields that need to be considered in the join.

Currently I'm working with something like the following -

```
Select * from 
dbo.datatable dt
inner join dbo.hierarchy h
on dt.profileid = h.profileid
AND dt.date >= h.startdate
AND dt.date < h.enddate
```

I've got a clustered index on `dt` that includes `date` and `profileid` and a clustered index on `h` that includes `startdate`, `enddate`, and `profileid`. SSMS has also suggested a couple indexes that I've added as well that include a lot of the data fields.

I cannot change the format of the hierarchy, but the view is absurdly slow when I try to pull a large number of days in a sql query. This dataset is end-user facing, so it's gotta be fast and usable.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider changing the order of the clustered index so that `profileid` is first.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/interval-queries-sql-server

Comment: @RickJames wouldn't that cause issues in the data table's efficiency? Currently it's in the order Date, Interval, ProfileID.

Comment: @JesúsLópez thanks for the article, I read it and tried some of the indexing I could understand, but a lot of it was a bit over my skill level. I'm reaching out to some others on my team for assistance to see if we can implement more of it; appreciate the assist!

Comment: Always put range predicate columns (> and <) **AFTER** all other equality (=) columns and before inequalities (<>)

Comment: @Charlieface That is utter nonsense. The optimizer is free to rearrange the query and does - the order of boolean expressions joined using "AND" makes absolutely no difference. It might be easier to read and understand that way, but the optimizer does not care.

Comment: @Smor Sorry I was talking about the index key columns. Obvs your right about the actual query

Comment: @JordanMoore - If you usually include a test on profiled, my change would _improve_ locality of reference.  Or you could add a non-clustered secondary index(profile, date) for some performance benefit.

Comment: @JordanMoore that technique (RI Tree) is really difficult to implement correctly. What I would try first is an index on dbo.hierachy with profileid as the first column, then startdate and enddate, including all columns referenced in the query

Comment: @RickJames changing the index to have the identifying agentIDs first fixed everything, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In both tables, put `profileId` *first* in the likely index.  This is because it is tested with `=`.

Alas, that is probably the only optimization you can do.  Looking at a date range degenerates into using only one of the tests, and leads to scanning up to half the table.  Or, after testing profileId, scanning half the rows for that profileId.

If the start-end ranges never overlap, there may be a trick to make things faster, but it will involve changes to the schema and code.